# Clutter Toolkit Dependencies - Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: c, opengl, ubuntu, pango, clutter

Is there an obvious way to get Clutter Toolkit up and running in Ubuntu. It seems like there is a huge list of dependencies as I try compiling it.

The current dependency which I am unable to resolve is "cogl-pango-1.0".

Any suggestions on getting up a running with Clutter, for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11.04 already ships with clutter 1.6.14: http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/libclutter-1.0-0

see also: http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/natty/clutter-1.0 for the development and documentation packages.

the dependencies list is not "huge": most of the requirements are already available in 11.04 as -devel or -dev.

if you want to build from sources, I can recommend using jhbuild: the necessary steps are provided here: http://wiki.clutter-project.org/wiki/BuildingClutter#Building_from_Git

Comment: Whoops, don't know what I was thinking about the version number. I guess I will use the pre-built version. I was having trouble getting the previously mentioned dependencies while building with jhbuild.